# Give an aggregate a converting constructor?

Tags: c++, constructor, c++20, aggregate-initialization

I'm writing a large fixed-size integer type that is made up of multiple `uint64_t`s, like in the (simplified) example below.  I would like my type to behave like the built-in integer types, which means (among other things) that:

1. it should be uninitialized if you don't assign a value to it, and
2. it should accept widening from other built-in integer types.

It appears to me, however, that one cannot write a type that simultaneously satisfies both properties.  This is because property 1 requires the type to be an aggregate, which means it must have no constructors, and we need a constructor to implement property 2.

Is there any way to write a large integer type that satisfies both properties?

```
#include <array>
#include <cstdint>

struct uint128_t{
    std::array<uint64_t, 2> data;
};

int main(){
    uint128_t x; // uninitialized (good)
    uint128_t y = 100; // can we make this work while ensuring that the previous line still works?
}
```

Comment: You could add an empty default constructor `uint128_t() {}`. Your `struct` is no longer an aggregate; but why do you say this is a problem?

Comment: @fabian Fixed.  It shouldn't affect the solution in any way.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A constructor such as `uint128_t() {}` will leave your array uninitialized by default. Ability to leave members uninitalized has nothing to do with being an aggregate.

But there's a better option: `uint128() = default;`. It will cause `uint128_t x;` to be uninitialized, but `uint128_t x{};` will be zeroed, just like with built-in types.

Answer (score 1):

> This is because property 1 requires the type to be an aggregate, which means it must have no constructors

No, it could have empty constructors

```
class uint128_t{
public:
    // this is an empty constructor, it does not initializes data
    uint128_t() {}; 
    // calling this ctor will create an object with an initial value "val"
    uint128_t(uint64_t val)
        :data{0, val} {}
    // for larger numbers
    uint128_t(std::string_view src) {
        // implement it yourself
    }
private:
    std::array<uint64_t, 2> data;
};
```